# Effective Design for Light-Powered Aircraft Engines?

Tags: science-based, engineering, light, aircraft, engines

**How would aircraft engines be designed which use magic orbs able to output insane amounts of light for power?**

In this **industrial era** setting, ordinary engines exist and are the cheapest option for many applications. However, by far the most powerful and lightweight engines are powered by glowing intangible orbs. With the orbs able to output essentially arbitrary amounts of sustained energy as visible light.

The most powerful psychics can produce lasers from these orbs up to powerful enough to melt through anything like a lightsaber, ***so the actual limit on engine power is whatever the materials used can withstand.*** Given the tech level tungsten is more precious than gold and can only be used sparingly.

Avatars can be manifested or dispelled by psychics at will within their line of sight, moved around at nearly lightspeed (but not through opaque barriers), and psychics perceive all the visible/near-UV light it absorbs.

Comment: VTC: There isn't a worldbuilding problem here. Like Edgar Rice Burroughs' *John Carter of Mars* books (which used a fanciful and magical *ninth ray of light* to justify super-fast lighter-than-air flight) you've elected to use a magical and infinitely powerful light source. OK, what is it you're asking for? An engine design? Technobabble? Surround the ball with solar panels and make it so, number one! I don't even know what you mean by "effective." You appear to have a good idea. What's your question?

Comment: You're gluing yourself in not very useful details for the question : Among others, orbs' price (just tell we can go as expensive as we want, we know we're talking about airships using these orbs), its color or how psychics are firing Superman's laser rays x). Moreover, you're going multiple directions at once : Asking for engine is not asking for plane, so telling they invented a simili-carbon fiber material -more likely used for the plane's structure- seems irrelevant.[...]

Comment: [...] And to close it all... We don't know how your orb works, you just say it gives "unlimited poooowwweeeer" (* insert evil laugh here *) how can we design an engine for you then? If it's the whole plane you actually want, why don't you replicate our good old planes?

Comment: @Tortliena  Deleted extraneous details. As I said before *power is not the limiting factor materials are*. I'm looking for viable engine designs for aircraft *given the tech level*.

Answer (score 2):

**Magical-Thermal Propulsion**

Simply use air as both your propulsion and coolant to protect surrounding materials. Essentially a jet engine without combustion chambers or jet fuel. Use a direct air cycle. A compression section directs intake air towards a chamber containing the orb, which heats it up while simultaneously cooling the chamber. The hot air is sent through a turbine which generates the power for the compressor section and then out the exhaust, producing thrust.

Simple, reliable, quick starting, and easy. Just a jet engine minus the jet fuel.

If you want something less 'modern' you can use turboprops which function on a similar foundation.

All this technology was designed in the 1930s and such, so its not too difficult.

This is almost identical to the aircraft nuclear-thermal propulsion system in the 60s except instead of a nuclear reactor its a magical orb. (far more lightweight and cleaner)

Fuel is no longer an issue, and your aircraft can stay in the air indefinitely while being extremely lightweight.

Comment: Pretty much. Make a turbine and use the light instead of combusting fuel to heat the air. That's all a turbine is. Works with piston engines too. Are turboprops less modern than jet engines? Pretty sure jet engines came first.

Answer (score 0):

**Laser Ablation Thruster**

This is mostly based off a [paper on the subject](https://www.colorado.edu/faculty/kantha/sites/default/files/attached-files/44233-36621_-_bradley_wyatt_-_dec_19_2012_1126_pm_-_final_project_wyatt.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20other%20form%20of%20electric,to%20create%20a%20plasma%20jet.), but the basics is this - in theory, you have a lot of power if you can create a 'powerful enough to melt through anything like a lightsaber', that's a lot of energy, so the goal is to redirect it somehow, and the somehow is the laser ablation thruster.

Essentially, you put a propellant in front of the laser generation, the propellant turns into plasma, and et voila, you have a thruster. Now, in general, the current variation of this device is used on the micro scale, but it could in theory be scaled up. If you combine that with an ultralight, then it's very possible to create a powered aircraft engine. There are a few drawbacks, like the intense heat generation for one, and the fact that you need a constant supply on new propellant blocks, but it's very doable.

Comment: Do you know if something like this can be done using much simpler tech? Superconducting magnets weren't exactly available in the industrial era.

Comment: @VakusDrake Not the first proposed engine in the paper, the second, it doesn't require superconductors.